# Meaning of "34th and Vine"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

While looking at the answer given to the question: ["I live on 7th Street and 8th avenue. What does it mean? How can you live on two streets?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/25024/on-7th-street-and-8th-avenue)

I read:

> “34th and Vine” will pin things down for anyone who knows the city and wants to know what neighborhood you live in, or how to get there and how long it will take.'

No I wonder  what “and Vine” stands for? I cannot find it on any NYC plan. Can anyone tell me?

Comment: Where did you get the reference "34th and Vine" from? Do you know the lyrics of the song "Love potion no 9"? 34th and Vine is in there. I read somewhere that the reference was purely fictional. So don't let that confuse you.

Comment: The naming system is not limited to New York, but can be used for any city with a grid street pattern, which includes most major cities in the United States. In some city, if there is a road named *34th Blvd.* and a road named *Vine Ave.* which intersect, you can tell people you live at *34th and Vine* to say you live near that intersection.

Comment: It’s in Kansas City! Vine is mentioned in other songs. Kansas City Blues.

Comment: @chosterI It's not limited to NYC and cities with grid patterns.  It can be used anyplace two roads cross.  Even in rural areas!  *I live at County Road 6 and Range Line Road*.  See?  Just as in a city, that would mean I live in the vicinity of that intersection.

Answer (score 1):

> I live on 7th Street and 8th avenue. What does it mean? How can you
>   live on two streets?

It means *close to the corner* of those streets (streets and avenues usually cross).

There's **Wine:34** restaurant along 34th Street, not sure if it's related to 'Vine'.

Comment: This system makes sense when a city is built on a grid plan with long streets, as many cities in the US are.

Answer (score 0):

**“34th and Vine”  would mean something like 34th Street and Vine Avenue, and would refer to the point where they cross.**

When a city is laid out as a grid, it is convenient to assign streets in one direction and avenues in the other direction.

On the the NY map, you can see that, for example, East 38th Street intersects with Park Avenue.  You could identify the place where they cross as **38th and Park**, or more conventionally as **Park Ave & E 38th St**

[image]